# Javascript function not triggering from Jquery Datatables row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table that uses datatables and I want to trigger a function when I select a link on a row like this:

```
<script>
        var selected = Array();
        var form_data = {
            "Id": "@Model.ApplicationDetails.Id"
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $("#table").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("GetApplicationRoles", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "data": form_data,
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "filter":false,
                "language": {
                    "search": "",
                    "searchPlaceholder": " Search"
                },
                "ordering": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                             var url = "@Url.Action("EditRole", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())/" + data.Id;
                            return "<a href='#' class='select-item' data-id='"+data.Id+"'>" + data.RoleName + "</i></a>"
                        }, "name": "RoleName"
                    }
                ],
                "responsive": true,
                "processing":true,
                "serverSide": true,
            }).columns.adjust()
            .responsive.recalc();
            new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
        });

        $("#table tbody").on('click',".select-item",function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test");
            return false;
            //e.preventDefault();
            //console.log($(this).data("id"));
        });
    </script>
```

As you can see, when a user clicks on this row:

```
<a href='#' class='select-item' data-id='"+data.Id+"'>" + data.RoleName + "</i></a>
```

The function at the bottom should trigger. However, right now the only thing that happens is that my url is appended by a hash#. I think I missed something but I can't seem to catch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a delegated event handler, which is correct. However one issue is because the primary selector needs to be an element that is present in the DOM when the page loads. The `tbody` element is also dynamically generated, so the event handler is not attached correctly.

To fix this, attach the event to the `#table` directly:

```
$('#table').on('click', '.select-item', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("test");
});
```

You also need to move that code block *inside* the `document.ready` event handler.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much. I was so close. I'll accept this answer in 10 minutes.